# Mac HDD still losing space after deleting files

Tags: macos, video, disk-space

I'm working on videos. I'm capturing them with a software and I save them as MP4. Then I compress them as MOV. After that I upload them to YouTube. However I lose about 1.5 GB from my hard disk while I'm doing this. (I delete these videos after I upload.)

How can I fix this situation?

Comment: Are you using finder to measure free disk space on OS X or another tool? Have you [ruled out local Time Machine backup snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4878) as a reason why the system would retain these files after you delete them?

Answer (score 1):

it could be just used a swap space that should be cleared up by a reboot (probably some terminal command too).

Could also be you are on a laptop with time machine and have mobile backups enabled (aka [local snapshots](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4878)).

Comment: well I'm on laptop and I'm sure I'm loosing because of videos. I'm checking storage left and it decreases after video capture & edit.

Comment: so do you use time machine?

Answer (score -2):

Could you try:

Finder --> Preference --> Advance --> select Empty Trash securely. After that, empty your Trash.

I got the same problem and now it's working after fixing like that.